# PdfFonts.GetFontMetrics, font 'Arial' step #40: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: fonts, asp.net-core-webapi, stimulsoft

I have Exception error when Report.ExportDocument in asp.net core 3.1 like bellow code
the Error :
"Exception in PdfFonts.GetFontMetrics, font 'Arial' step #40: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array".
Please Help ME how to solved this error!!!

```
 StiReport Report = new StiReport();
 Report.Load($"{path}\\Repot\\Mahdi.mrt");
 Report.Render();
 Report.ExportDocument(StiExportFormat.Pdf, $"{path}\\Repot\\MyPdf.pdf", Settings);
```

Comment: I suggest you could try to add the font info file and to use the font info file you should add the information about the necessary fonts to FontsInfoStore with the following:
Stimulsoft.Report.Export.FontsInfoStore.LoadFontInfoToStore("Arial", "Arial.fiz");

Comment: If you feel my reply has helped you, please mark it as answer, so that other folks who face the same issue could find the solution more easily. Thank you.

Comment: The code not working could you please help me more

Comment: When there are Persian letters in the set data I get this error again!!! but in export to jpeg I do not have any error

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could try to add the font info file and to use the font info file you should add the information about the necessary fonts to FontsInfoStore with the following:

`Stimulsoft.Report.Export.FontsInfoStore.LoadFontInfoToStore("Arial", "Arial.fiz");`